# topTabNavigator label not showing

Tags: react-native, label, react-navigation-top-tabs

I have the following tobtabNavigator but the labels are not showing and I am not sure why. It is just blank as shown bellow
[image]

```js
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const DeustchScreen = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarLabelStyle: {fontSize: 12, color: 'red'},
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="a" component={Deutsch} />
      <Tab.Screen name="b" component={Deutsch} />
      <Tab.Screen name="c" component={Deutsch} />
      <Tab.Screen name="d" component={Deutsch} />
      <Tab.Screen name="e" component={Deutsch} />
      <Tab.Screen name="f" component={Deutsch} />
      <Tab.Screen name="g" component={Deutsch} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check here in this snack, your code is working :

https://snack.expo.dev/-aQ4MaWt7

[image]

Hope it helps .feel free for doubts

Comment: You are using the top tab navigation directly inside the navigation container. I however put it afterwards into a stack navigator which in turn is used in the drawer navigation. So I am wondering if it is the nesting that is causing the issue

Comment: Share an expo snack please

Comment: I tried to create this minimal code but I am still facing the same issue. I even tried removing the stack navigator and adding the tab navigator directly same issue. I am not sure why it is not working on my actual project and it is working here https://snack.expo.dev/@yousser/configuring-the-header-bar-%7C-react-navigation

Comment: @Babou i can see its working here

Comment: umm what should i do to rpelicate

Comment: That is the problem I am not able to replica it through snack

Comment: umm then surely some problem in your code , coz ideally it should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248005/discussion-between-babou-and-gaurav-roy).

Answer (score 0):

I was using @react-native-community/viewpager instead of react-native-pager-view. Also in the screenOptions, I needed to specify `tabBarItemStyle: {width:100}`